# page extension with tinyMCE django-cms

Tags: django, tinymce, django-cms

Hi everyone I create a page Extension using the [documentation of Django CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/extending_page_title.html) and work perfectly,

Now I have a two text_area in my extension page, I want to include TinyMCE library to my text_area

for this I have this in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from cms.extensions import PageExtension
from cms.extensions.extension_pool import extension_pool


class IconExtension(PageExtension):

  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons', blank=True)
  description_short = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Short Description")
  description_large = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Large Description")

extension_pool.register(IconExtension)
```

and my admin.py have this

```
# from django.forms import *
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from django import forms
from django.db.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.extensions import PageExtensionAdmin
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


from .models import IconExtension

class IconExtensionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  some_field = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}))

  class Meta:
    model = IconExtension
    fields = '__all__'


class IconExtensionAdmin(PageExtensionAdmin):
  form = IconExtensionForm

admin.site.register(IconExtension, IconExtensionAdmin)
```

right now I obtain this error

```
jquery.tinymce.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.tinymce.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ jquery.tinymce.min.js:1
init_tinymce.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

my setting.py file have this configuration

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = '/static/js/tinymce/'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
```

I look for the solution in internet and everybody say that I load the jquery library before... in my case my field with TinyMCE is inside of popup, the page have load the popup have the jquery Library in second time.. bootstrap is the first.

When I inspect the element inside the popup, my load library are this

```
<head>
<title>
Change icon extension | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css">
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_utc_offset__ = "\u002D18000";</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/djangocms_admin_style/css/djangocms-admin.css">

    <script src="/static/djangocms_admin_style/js/dist/bundle.adminstyle.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/en/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/django_tinymce/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/django_tinymce/init_tinymce.js"></script>

    <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
    </head>
```

any idea how to include tinyMCE in page extension, I am in the right way?

Comment: I've replied with more complex answer but just to point out a small typo in your code - you are importing * from django.forms but not the forms themselves, thus forms.ModelForm is not found. Using just ModelForm would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is specific requirement to use TinyMCE, I would recommend using integration that is already built into the Django CMS Text module ([CKEditor](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor)).

```
# models.py 

class Model1(models.Model):
    text = HTMLField(configuration='CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL1')

class Model2(models.Model):
    text = HTMLField(configuration='CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL2')

# settings.py

CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL1 = {
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['ShowBlocks'],
        ['Format', 'Styles'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ]
}

CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL2 = {
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @petr I have to use TinyMCE, I do some change in my admin.py , and now when I open my page extension I have this new error. `'tinymce-spellcheck' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` any idea about that?

Comment: Looks like it's missing the URL with alias "tinymce-spellcheck". Maybe you've missed some internal URL setup? The editor will probably call your site via AJAX to do spellcheck on the text

Comment: Hi @petr, thanks so much you all right, I forget to put `url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),` in my `urls.py` file. But now I have this new error `jquery.tinymce.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.tinymce.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ jquery.tinymce.min.js:1
init_tinymce.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined` I change my request to add my setting file respect to tinyMCE. I look for google and everybody said that I have to read before Jquery library that I have. Any idea!

Comment: We are now moving to front-end side... I would examine the source of the page to see if 1. all tinyMCE related scripts are included 2. they are in correct order.

Comment: Hi @petr I include the header of my popup in the question.